# How can I change date from 24-hours format to 12-hours format (am/pm) in android

Tags: android, time-format

```
Calendar ci = Calendar.getInstance();

CiDateTime = "" + (ci.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) +  
    "/" + ci.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 
    "/" + ci.get(Calendar.YEAR);

String visitdatetime = CiDateTime + "" + 
          ci.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + 
          ci.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + 
          ci.get(Calendar.SECOND);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy  hh:mm  a");
```

I am getting from the server in 24 hours format.but want to show my date like MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM like 12 hrs format.

Comment: I don't see your problem. your formatter seems correct. what is wrong?

Comment: actually I cannot change it..

Comment: smthing error is thr..java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Comment: i think there is a part missing in your question. I think it is more about parsing the date than formatting it. What is the format you receive the date from the server in? can you paste a example of date? (it is probably a standard format, there are tons of tools to parse it.)

Answer (score 10):

Did you try this ?

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFromat= new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy  hh:mm  aa");
Date today = new Date();
String todayStr = dateFromat.format(today);
```

Answer (score 5):

Below function may be useful to you. This will convert time from 24 hours to 12 hours

```
public static String Convert24to12(String time)
{
    String convertedTime ="";
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat displayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = parseFormat.parse(time);        
        convertedTime=displayFormat.format(date);
        System.out.println("convertedTime : "+convertedTime);
    } catch (final ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return convertedTime;
    //Output will be 10:23 PM
}
```

Comment: I want to change coplete date format..so what can I do..I need to get date like this only above i have written this

Comment: please see my que and check..visitdatetime..I am getting date like date..and I want to parse it..so plz help me for that

Answer (score 2):

```
public static final String TIME_FORMAT = "hh:mm aa";
SimpleDateFormat TimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(TIME_FORMAT);

Calendar ATime = Calendar.getInstance();
String Timein12hourFormat = TimeFormat.format(ATime.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

try with this answer this is shortest and best answer on stack.

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss aa");
 Datetime = sdf.format(c.getTime());
 System.out.println("============="+Datetime);
```

Result:-=========2015-11-20 05:52:25 PM

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to get a data in US-English Format date/time using a 12 hour clock.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
01/16/2014 03:53:57 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

`hh:mm a`

Adding the 'a' should do the trick in displaying the am/pm

In angular i am using angular-bootsrap-datetimepicker and to display the selected date and time i am using this syntax

`data-ng-model="event.start | date:'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a'"`

Answer (score -3):

use below format to 12 hour with am/pm

MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a